# Multiple Google Recaptcha with VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, recaptcha

I've got a question regarding using Google's Invisible Recaptcha when using an AJAX form submission using Vue components.

I've created a VueJS component which I include in the following 'recaptcha button' component in:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if="failed" style="color: red;"><strong>Sorry, the captcha validation failed. Please try again.</strong></div>
        <div :id="name"></div>

        <button :class="classes" type="button" @click="validate()">
            <slot>Submit</slot>
        </button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            default: 'recaptcha',
            required: false
        },
        classes: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        },
    },
    data: function ()
    {
        return {
            failed: false,
        };
    },
    mounted: function ()
    {
        this.initReCaptcha();
    },
    methods: {
        initReCaptcha: function() {
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(typeof grecaptcha === 'undefined') {
                    self.initReCaptcha();
                }
                else {
                    grecaptcha.render(self.name, {
                        sitekey: 'site-key-here',
                        size: 'invisible',
                        badge: 'inline',
                        callback: self.response
                    });
                }
            }, 100);
        },
        validate: function ()
        {
            grecaptcha.execute();
        },
        response: function (token)
        {
            this.$parent.fields['g-recaptcha-response'] = token;
            this.$parent.submit();
        }
    },

}

</script>
```

As you can see, I'm assigning Google's Recaptcha's callback function to the current instance of the recaptcha component's 'response' function. However, when I submit one of the forms, it seems to be calling the response function of the other component on the page.. and therefore trying to call submit on a form that has no input in so far..

We thought it might be a case of the recaptcha rendering not actually creating two instances and therefore on the second one, the callback is just being overwritten, but from logging the components in the mounted function, the form that's being submitted instead of the one we're trying to submit is being instantiated first, which lead us to believe it's not a case of overwriting...

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
PM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, did not know that the render function returned the widget ID.  grecaptcha.execute() will just execute the first widget in the global list if not given an optional widget ID parameter.

To tackle this, assign the widget ID returned by the render function to a data property in the component and then within the validate function, call execute with that widget ID as the parameter.

```
self.widgetId = grecaptcha.render(self.name, {...});

validate: function ()
{
    grecaptcha.execute(this.widgetId);
},
```